# Trabalhando com arquivos PDF em server NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

Olá,

Tenho um serviço que ao realizar um request via postman por exemplo, recebo um arquivo .pdf

Estou chamando esse serviço a partir de um novo serviço nodeJS, porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que o .pdf seja retornado em uma chamada.

Recebo uma string com o conteúdo "%PDF-1.3 \n%���� \n1 0 obj \n<< \n/Type /Catalog \n/Pages 2 0 R \n/PageMode..."

Realizo a comunicação entre os serviços usando request do nodeJS

```
return new Promise( async (resolve,reject) => {          
          request({
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
              },
              url: url,
              method: 'GET',
            }, function (error, response, body) {                    
              if (error) {
                reject(error);
              } else {
                resolve(response.body);
              } 
            });
      });
    }
```

E em meu serviço adiciono as informações no header

```
.then((result) =>{                
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'form-data; name="arquivo.pdf";     filename="arquivo.pdf"');
    res.status(200).send(result) }
```

Como posso fazer para que o meu serviço seja apenas o meio de campo entre o serviço que disponbiliza o .pdf e uma chamada ajax?

Preciso de preferencia exibir esse .pdf no browser, ou realizar o download.

Comment: Qual o problema de _"%PDF-1.3 \n%���� \n1 0 obj \n<< \n/Type /Catalog \n/Pages 2 0 R \n/PageMode..."_? O PDF é um texto, esse texto não é o PDF desejado ou você não o está lendo com um "interpretador" (que deve transformar essa string em um arquivo PDF entendível)?

Comment: Como faço para tranformar o "%PDF-1.3 \n%���� \n1 0 obj \n<< \n/Type /Catalog \n/Pages 2 0 R \n/PageMode..." de volta a um arquivo PDF?

O pdf contém texto e imagens.

Comment: Basta abrir essa string com um leitor de PDF (essa string estaria num arquivo), colocar dentro de um `<object>` (HTML), algo assim

Comment: Faço um ajax para meu seviço, e ao incluir a resposta em um HTML é exibido o texto na página HTML

Comment: O texto exibido ainda é no formato %PDF-1.3 \n%���� \n1 0 obj \n<< \n/Type /Catalog \n/Pages 2 0 R \n/PageMode..."

Comment: Como você fez? Quando digo dentro do `object` na verdade é algo como `<object data="url-pro-recurso.pdf"></object>`. Se for assincrono pode transformar em base64 e colocar a url em base64

Comment: Colque o código do `resolve(response.body);`?

Comment: Você deve ler esse texto com um leitor de PDF, como você tá lendo? Postman? Ele não transforma isso num PDF (eu acho)

Comment: Chamando pelo postman ele transforma em PDF, mas ao abrir recebo a mensagem que o arquivo está corrompido.

Preciso chamar meu serviço via ajax e exibir esse pdf no navegador ou realizar o download

Comment: Eu estou chamando o serviço assim:

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/get-pdf",
  success: function(response) {
        var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", response);
        ifrm.style.width = "640px";
        ifrm.style.height = "480px";
  document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    }
});

Mas o pdf não é exibido, o que continua sendo exibido é a mensagem:
"%PDF-1.3 \n%���� \n1 0 obj \n<< \n/Type /Catalog \n/Pages 2 0 R \n/PageMode..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução: O texto ainda era exibido em formato de string devido a codificação do request

Removi a Promise e fiz direto na função, que chamava ela. Adicionei *'encoding': 'null'* no request e alterei setHeader. A chamada ficou assim:

```
    try{
        request({
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            encoding: null
            }, function (error, response, body) {                    
            if (error) {
                logger.error("ERROR: " + error);
            } else {
                res.contentType("application/pdf");
                res.send(response.body);
            } 
        });
    }
```

Para exibir no navegador, usei o  XMLHttpRequest() fazendo o response virar um blob, a partir disso com o URL.createObjectURL abri o pdf em nova aba